# Bug or not? Accordion doesn't work properly on 0.7.0

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to do rather normal thing: show accordion with first element open.

```
  <accordion close-others="true">
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="$first">
    <accordion-heading>
      {{group.title}} <i class="pull-right" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-down': isopen, 'icon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div ng-repeat="item in group.content">{{item.title}}</div>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

is-open= "$first" almost solves the problem,

**updated**

<strike>http://plnkr.co/edit/CODNWD7WiBHDfYHHuK7C?p=preview</strike>
http://plnkr.co/edit/4jYuw2?p=preview

but look at icon-chevron - it is still down. And when I click - it expands and collapses, but icons are still down...

Comment: plunker works fine for me.  I see the chevron go from right to down when opened and back to right when close.

Comment: added this `<accordion close-others="false" ng-init="section1.isOpen=true">` and seems to work fine. Your `ng-class` for icon is set based on `section1.isOpen`

Comment: Very sorry - wrong plunker!!! The old plunker of cours works - but first group isn't open at start

Answer (score 0):

I've cloned your plunkr and it works with a couple of changes:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1IHE5lRmm0oZzeHekkkZ?p=preview

Here you can see how your code looks like now:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
    <accordion-heading>
      {{group.title}} <i class="pull-right" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-down': group.open, 'icon-chevron-right': !group.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div ng-repeat="item in group.content">{{item.title}}</div>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

This way you'll have the first tab opened by default and working closed-opened icons.